# Spark Streaming with Kafka Problem: AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have an issue while using Spark Streaming and Kafka: I am running Spark 3.5.0 and Kafka 3.5 on my virtual machine (VMWare), and I want to read messages from my laptop with Spark Streaming (which is on the same network as my virtual machine). However, I encounter the error 'AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide.' I have tried creating a Python producer on my laptop and sending messages to the Kafka consumer on the virtual machine, and the consumer successfully receives messages. Also try to run this script with Jupyter notebook on my virtual machine and it's still running ok. So i dont know why I can not run on my laptop?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import os

os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8'

KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = "192.168.xxx.xxx:9092"
KAFKA_TOPIC = "test"

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test_stream").master("local[*]").config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.5.0").getOrCreate()

df = spark.readStream.format("kafka") \
    .option("bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS) \
    .option("subscribe", KAFKA_TOPIC) \
    .load()

df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
```

AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide.

I want to know any way to solve this error

Comment: Are you running this code in `pyspark` utitility?

Comment: i was run this code with pyspark (jupyter note book on VScode on my virtual machine) and this code running well.

Comment: How do you run this script in your VM ?

Comment: i just install anaconda and vscode on my VM and run this code with jupyter note book on vscode. This code still running with no error but in my case. I want to test with another laptop/pc in LAN network (same network with my VM)